# Regular expression for /

Tags: python, regex

I am trying a regular expression through the Python re module to match both of these patterns:

```
"GET /images/launch-logo.gif HTTP/1.0"
"GET / HTTP/1.0 "
```

I tried the following expression:

```
"(\S+) (\S.*?)\s*(\S*)"
```

This does as expected by returning the following:

```
1. GET
2. /images/launch-logo.gif
3. HTTP/1.0
```

However, for the second one it returns:

```
1. GET
2. / HTTP/1.0
3. ''
```

Instead, I would like that to return the following:

```
1. GET
2. / 
3. HTTP/1.0
```

There is also a trailing space that needs to be removed. Could some one help me with the right regular expression?

Comment: What about just splitting on spaces?

Comment: This is part of a longer regex...can't really use anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a reluctant quantifier (`*?`) here. Use:

```
(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*
```

The problem with your original regex is the combination of `.*?` and `\s*`, since the reluctant expression can keep matching while `\s*` doesn't have to match anything.

Comment: This works fine for the first case but not for the second case

Comment: Added additional `\s*` for the trailing whitespace